# Unable to achieve the a new line when when appending a content to StringBuffer object usint "\n"

Tags: java, string

i have written method which takes the big string and breaks into two lines :

```
private String  getNameSplited(String name){
char[] sAr = name.toCharArray();

StringBuffer strBuff = new StringBuffer(name.length());
    boolean start = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < sAr.length; i++) {
        if(i > 20) {
            if(sAr[i] == ' ' && start){
                strBuff.append("\n");
                start = false;
            } else {
                strBuff.append(sAr[i]);
            }
        } else {
            strBuff.append(sAr[i]);
        }
    }
    return strBuff.toString();
}
```

In this method "\n" is not working.
As in my project we are not using direct System.out.println();

we are using out.print(strBuff); to print this string in a dialog.

So can cany one give suggestion how to make this code work . 
Thanks you...

Comment: What dialog are you talking about? Is it desktop GUI? Or html?

Comment: And how about using `StringBuilder.newLine()` method?

Comment: @Rekin What is `StringBuilder.newLine()` method? I can't find it in javadoc.

Comment: @NikitaBeloglazov: Sorry - I confused StringBuilder with BufferedWriter. The latter has the method: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html#newLine()

Answer (score 5):

`\n` might not be the newline character in the given system. Use `System.getProperty("line.separator")` to get the line separator corresponding to the runtime environment.

Use `strBuff.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));` Or store `System.getProperty("line.separator")` as a constant and use it wherever you need a new line.

Comment: I like the second option, usually i put everytime strBuff.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));, the second option is nice.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try something like this?

```
    strBuff.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "line.seperator" property if the output destination is a file
`strBuff.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"))`

Comment: you can use the html '<br>' tag if output is a webpage